# Can I build games w/ Construct 2 and compile w/ new VS 2013 Cordova support?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, construct-2, visual-studio-cordova

After noticing the added support for Apache Cordova builds into Update 2 of Visual Studio 2013, I wonder if it could be possible to create a game with Construct 2, export as phonegap app and build using this new VS feature.

Thanks in advance,

Marcelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is whether you should be able to take a PhoneGap project and convert it, then yes.  However, they may need to tweak some things around plugins and config.xml depending on how old the project is.  (Ex: There are some things in config.xml that are phonegap only)

1. Basically, copy the contents of what would go into the “www” folder into the root of the project.
2. On plugins:

   a. If they are using base Cordova plugins, then they can just go
   click the plugins in the manifest editor

   b. If they used a PhoneGap CLI project, then for plugins they can actually copy the contents of their “plugins” folder to a “plugins” folder in the VS project

   c. If they were referencing custom non-base plugins via feature elements (the old Cordova 2.x way), then they may need to make some adjustments – Mainly because plugins like push and barcode aren’t in plugins.cordova.io yet